# Importing date column ends in error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

While i try to upload a flatfile which contains date fields with data type `DATE` in ssms import/export wizard  throws an error like below

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

**Actual data in flat file**

```
  Period
12/17/2003
01/01/0001
10/25/2001
01/01/0001
```

Please help me how to upload those dates ..... i know error which lies in fileds which contains '01/01/0001' but it is business logic i cant able to change those data.... !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want, when this data comes. simply eigher you change your datatype first varchar and import it and then change the problematic value to null and then finally change the datatype to datetime.

Comment: But while i try to import those values with varchar 01/01/0001 stores as it exists but other dates are stored like follows.... for `12/17/2003` it stores as `37972` later i cant able to change those to `Date` datatype

Comment: You can able to change the 37972 to 12/17/2003. Look into my answer and update your status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, One possibility to convert the Date in integer(37972) to DATETIME after the insertion is by using dateadd.

Run the below query, after you Insert the values into VARCHAR type column.

```
 UPDATE YourTableName 
 SET ColumnWithVarcharType = CAST(DATEADD(d, 
      CAST(ColumnWithVarcharType AS INT), -2) AS VARCHAR(20))
 WHERE IsNumeric(ColumnWithVarcharType) = 1
```

Above query will update only the selected values having integer(37972) value. It won't care about values like '01/01/0001'.

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, 0)   => 1/1/1900
SELECT DATEADD(d, 37972, -2)  => 12/17/2003
```

by default the DB return the initial date used in the sql server for the query `SELECT DATEADD(d, 0, 0)`. In the same way you can add the 37972 to the Initial date like `SELECT DATEADD(d, 37972, -2)`.

Comment: i tried your update query but it throws this error - `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'`.

Comment: UPDATE YourTableName 
 SET ColumnWithVarcharType = DATEADD(d, ColumnWithVarcharType, -2) 
 WHERE IsNumeric(ColumnWithVarcharType) = 1

Comment: Already I removed ')'. Check the query again. UPDATE YourTableName SET ColumnWithVarcharType = DATEADD(d, ColumnWithVarcharType, -2) WHERE IsNumeric(ColumnWithVarcharType) = 1

Comment: Had u find the answer.

Comment: Actually while i tried your update query it still shows same error and `dateadd` method gives incorrect result to some values (result  shows two days additionally). I mean for 25 it shows 27 like that..

Comment: Yes, that is why I mention the query with -2 in it. Use It with -2. SELECT DATEADD(d, 37972, -2)

Answer (score 0):

Try  using `ISDATE function` which will tell you whether the given date is `Valid or not`.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Isdate('10/25/2001') = 1 THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), '10/25/2001',102 )
         ELSE NULL
       END
```

Comment: Above mentioned is actual date i have to maintain those formats it is business logic proposed by our clients

Comment: @CIPHER - Modified check now.

Comment: But while i try to import those values with varchar 01/01/0001 stores as it exists but other dates are stored like follows.... for 12/17/2003 it stores as 37972 later i cant able to change those to Date datatype...please give some method to convert those 37972 varchar into date

Comment: @CIPHER - So u need to insert `01/01/0001` this date into date column

Comment: My case is not to insert `01/01/0001` through query window ...iam trying to import via flatfile...it throws above mentioned error while i try to import with `date` datatype and while i try to import with varchar actual dates are converted like my above comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your input value: => **01/01/0001**

Immediate Workaround i can suggest is change your datatype in table from **datetime** to **date**

```
select cast('01/01/0001' as date)
or
select convert(date,'01/01/0001')
```

Output: 0001-01-01

```
select cast('01/01/0001' as datetime)
or
select convert(datetime,'01/01/0001')
```

Output: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.